# How to update column if value is not present in other table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I have a table `board` with unique column `id` and column `hide`. I have another table `pins` with a column `board_id` which is not unique. Every pins.board_id is also in board.id, and there can be multiple pins.board_id's that are the same.

Now I need to check every board.id to see whether it is present in any pins.board_id, and if not set `hide` to '1'. I imagine the way to do this is a join, but doesn't a join just match up where there IS the same value in both tables?

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join both tables using `LEFT JOIN`. The column that contains null value on `board_id` simply means that it doesn't exist.

```
UPDATE  board a
        LEFT JOIN pins b
            ON a.id = b.board_ID
SET     a.hide = 1
WHERE   b.board_ID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4d12/1)